# Sharepoint 2010 rename root title is not inheriting

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

In my Sharepoint Site i've got a problem with the breadcrumbs.
By default i named the Root "Portal Site", which was shown correctly in breadcrumb navi.
Later i changed the page title.

Root Site Breadcrumb is showing the new correct name.
Every TeamSite below shows the old value and cannot be changed somehow.

Does anybody know how this can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the Problem as follows:
- Opened SP Management PowerShell

- Pulled reference to SPSite
- Pulled RootWeb reference from SPSite
- Changed RootWeb's Title

It was the Title, which was all the time pulled from breadcrumb navigation